# how to use OOTB enum as an attribute type in custom Spring items.xml

Tags: spring, sap-commerce-cloud

I want to use an OOTB enum as a type in attribute tag for a custom qualifier that i am creating. Do I need to add anything for reference in the beginning of items.xml
Can any body help me with lines of code.

Comment: You do not require to add anything again on your *items.xml, just can simply use OOTB in your attribute type

Answer (score 1):

Simply refer the OOTB enum as a type for your attribute

Like

```
<attribute autocreate="true" qualifier="deliveryStatus" type="DeliveryStatus" generate="true">
     <persistence type="property"/>
     <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="true"/>
</attribute>
```